# How much overhead a cachedDistributed file has in a mapreduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How much overhead each cachedDistributed file has in a map-reduce program? I have a mapreduce program in which I need to have 50 cachedDistributed files (of very small size), it seems that the overhead they have is much larger than the case in which I have only 1 cachedDistributed file. Is that true?
As far as I understood, cachedDistributed files are copied to each machine that runs a mapper, thus access to a cachedDistributed file is local and shouldn't have too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to use archive files (files are unarchived on the task node automitically).
You can add archive files to the DistributedCache by to mean :

- With tool that use `GenericOptionsParser`. Then, you can specify the files to be distributed as a comma-separated list of URIs as the argument to `-archives` option. If you don't specify the scheme , the files are assumed to be local. So, when you launch the job, the local file is copied to the distributed filesystem (often HDFS)

  `$> hadoop jar foo.jar ClassUsingDistributedCacheFile -archives archive.jar input output`
- With the distributed cache API (see the javaDoc). With the API, the files specified by the URI must be in a shared filesystem (so the java API does not copy the file.

Before a task is run, the tasktracker copies the files from the distributed filesystem to a local disk, as you say. I think the overhead come from retrieving all your little files in the HDFS